# does blocking icmp also block traceroute?

Tags: networking

I am using an isp where I cannot ping google or any other website, but only the name resolution works.

I read somewhere on a internet site that traceroute is the opposite of ping.
Is this true ?

Also , if I block ping on my network - at the router level/layer 4 maybe - then is it true that traceroute will also fail ?

Answer (score 5):

Traceroute works by explicitly setting the *TTL* field to different values on outbound packets and observing which routers send the *ICMP TTL Exceeded* errors back for the different *TTL* values.

If all that is blocked is *ICMP Echo Request/Reply* ("ping"), this does not inherently block traceroute. However, one possible implementation for traceroute is to send specifically ICMP Echo Request packets.
Check the documentation for your traceroute program what it does send. Some implementations have an option to select sending either UDP packets or ICMP Echo Request packets.

Comment: My bad, for the late follow up. Apparently traceroute uses icmp by manipulating the TTL values in such a way that routers send back a time exceeded message. traceroute can use tcp and udp but they need a port, and icmp doesnt need a port right ? So if I do a tcp traceroute for port 80 which is commonly used, does it go from port 80 of one router to port 80 of next ?

Comment: They "need" a port, correct. But the implementation on Unix-like operating systems start at a certain port number and for each consecutive UDP packet sent, the port number gets incremented by one.

Answer (score 4):

By default traceroute sends UDP packets to track the route to a given host, while ping uses ICMP. But traceroute works processing ICMP packets returned by the routers in the route to the destination host.

This means that if you only block outgoing ICMP packets, ping won't work but traceroute will.

But if you block incoming ICMP packets traceroute won't be able to receive the ICMP responses from the routers in the route and then it won't work.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. On Unix-like operating systems, UDP is used by default but TCP or ICMP can be used as well. On Windows, ICMP packets are used by default. See the wikipedia article on traceroute & its sources.

Comment: You are right that is only the default behaviour, I omitted that for concreteness.

Comment: For completeness you must add that Windows uses ICMP for traceroute, i.e. blocking ICMP will make traceroute not work on his windows machines.